# Align to right an item inside a RowLayout

Tags: qt, qml

I want to align the last item inside a RowLayout to the right, but the item stays right after the other items even if the RowLayout has a bigger width than width of all children.
If i use `anchors.right:parent.right` it works well but then i get warnings.

```
ToolBar {
    height: globals.toolBar.height
    width:parent.width
background: Rectangle {
    anchors.fill: parent
    color:"white"
}

RowLayout {
    id: row
    anchors.fill: parent

    Button{
        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft
        contentItem: Image {
           source: "images/iconmenu.png"
         }
    }
    Button {
        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft
        contentItem: Image {
           source: "images/iconget.png"
        }
        ToolTip.text: qsTr("Get Data from Panel")
        ToolTip.visible: hovered
    }
    Button {
        id:buttonAbout
        Layout.alignment:Qt.AlignRight
        font.family: fontAwesomeSolid.font
        width:15
        height: 15
        text: "\uf129"
        ToolTip.text:qsTr("about")
        ToolTip.visible: hovered
        contentItem: Text {
            anchors.fill:buttonAbout
            anchors.right:buttonAbout.right
            anchors.topMargin: 3
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCente
            text: buttonAbout.text
        }
        background:
            Rectangle{
                width:20
                height: 20
                anchors.right: parent.right
                anchors.topMargin: 20
                radius:10
                border.width: 1
                border.color:"gray"
            }
        onClicked: popup.open()
    }
    Item {
        Layout.fillWidth: true
    }
}
}
```

---

### | | item 1| | item 2 | | item 3 | ------------------ |

what i want is this

---

### | | item 1| | item 2 |---------------------| item 3 ||

Comment: I always solve this kind of issue with an `Item` in between item 2 and item 3 in your case, then put `Layout.fillWidth: true`. But that's an ugly solution...

Comment: Why are You using RowLayout at all if you dont use any of the features of RowLayout. Use Row instead or align using anchors.

Comment: Ok @Luka using row is there a way to do what i want? Or shall i just position items with anchors?

Comment: @Nmaster88 if there will be no more than these 3 items, i would suggest anchors.

Comment: @Luka tbh im working with cases that have more than 4 items

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that Row and RowLayout doesn't let empty spaces to exist like that. But it can be solved using a component that does fillwidth:true

```
    Item{
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        height: buttonAbout.implicitHeight
        Button{
            id:buttonAbout
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar need and ended up swapping out a `Row` for an `Item` and then put a series of anchors in place to chain together the elements I needed horizontally lined up.

To get something like the requested:

| | item 1| | item 2 |---------------------| item 3 ||

I anchored item1.left to parent.left and item3.right to parent.right. Then, item2.left to item1.right and item2.right to item3.left.  Setting the widths for item 1 and item 3 implicitly sets the item 2 width.  If that doesn't quite work for you because item 2 needs to be a particular width (and you can't just have its content left aligned), throw in a dummy item X after it with nothing in it to fill in that empty space, and then build the anchor chain accordingly.

Such code is quite verbose, and obviously less than pretty, but the approach works and is fairly simple to implement.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is the ultimate best solution:

```
Button{
    id:buttonAbout
    Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignRight
}
```

Comment: Does not address the problem raised in the question.